# getting relative screen location

Tags: javascript, html

I`m kind of making my first steps in web programming and need to write some JS/HTML code that will enable the user to make an icon on his page.  I thought about showing the page and capture a click but there is the problem of different screen sizes and the browser may not be open widely on the entire screen. i know that in some other programming languages there are methods to take screen size and then one can use size/2 to do some thing at the middle of the screen but in HTML (as far as I saw) the location is always fixed.

Please advice.
Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 0):

with CSS you can use:

```
.elementClass{
    background: #999;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

here is [Css Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3WMgx/) you can resize the window..

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I don't need to resize the window. I want to let the user click and use the coordinate of the click to set an icon. I need a way to get the screen daimensions and relativy set an icon there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering just to pop it back. I'm sure there is an answer, since I'm new here I hope it is OK: Sorry for not being clear. I don't need to resize the window. I want to let the user click and use the coordinate of the click to set an icon. I need a way to get the screen daimensions and relativy set an icon there. –